# Going through tweets in multiple dictionaries in mulitple json files

Tags: python, json

I stored tweets into multiple json files using dictionaries where each dictionary contains information about one tweet. Within each dictionary, I stored the user id (key="uid"), tweet id (key="id"), text (key="txt"), and timestamp (key="ts") as separate keys.

Now I want to read in the dictionaries from the json files, remove the redundant tweets (as based on the tweet id), and store the resulting non-redundant tweets into a one large json file.

An example of the data within one of the json files is below:

```
{"id": 1234, "txt":"text here 123", "ts":"Wed, 03 Apr 2013 12:03:28 +0000", "uid":12345}
{"id": 2345, "txt":"more text here", "ts":"Tue, 02 Apr 2013 16:50:20 +0000", "uid":23456}
{"id": 1234, "txt":"text here 123", "ts":"Wed, 03 Apr 2013 12:03:28 +0000", "uid":12345}
```

Within the example, the first and third tweets are redundant. Hence, I would want to remove the third tweet.

The code I have so far is below. Since I created the code based on my (limited) experience with Python along with other examples on the web, it does not work. I get the following error: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 192 - line 1 column 10166 (char 192 - 10166)

I think I am on the right track, at least in terms of going through the files in the directory and removing the redundant tweets. But, I think my problem lies in properly loading and reading the json files. Any help, assistance, or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

(And no, I am not a student doing this for an assignment--I am a graduate student hoping to analyze Twitter data for my research.)

```
import string
import glob
import os
import simplejson as json

listoftweets = {} #to store all of the tweet ids

os.chdir("/mydir") #directory containing the json files with tweets

for f in glob.glob("*.json"):

    t = open(f,"r") #loading the json with tweets
    f1 = open(alltweets,"a") #open the json file to store all tweets

    for line in t:
        data = json.loads(line)
        tid = data['tweetid']

        if not listoftweets.has_key(tid): #if this isn't a redundant tweet
            json.dump(data,f1) #dump into the json file
            listoftweets[tid] = 0 #add this tweet id to the list

    t.close()
    f1.close()
```

**EDIT**

I have modified the code a bit. It seems as if the original data was not stored with each tweet on a new line--thanks Gary Fixler. Now that the issue is fixed, I am running into another error:
Traceback
...
    loads   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson__init__.py    451
    decode  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py 409
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 233 - line 2 column 1 (char 233 - 456)

A few other notes: Thanks Wesley Baugh--I implemented as many of the suggested changes as possible.

Also, there are too many tweets to load everything at one time--the tweets were continuously collected over a period of 3 months.

The updated code is below

```
listoftweets = {}
listoffiles = []

os.chdir("/mydir")

for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    listoffiles.append(str(f))

t2 = open("cadillaccue_newline.json",'a')

for files in listoffiles:
    t = open(files,'r')
    for line in t:
        text = line
        text = text.replace('}{','}\n{')
        t2.write(text)
    t.close()

t2.close()


t = open("cadillaccue_newline.json",'r')
f1 = open("cadillaccue_alltweets.json",'a')

for line in t:
    data = json.loads(line)
    tid = data['id']

    if tid not in listoftweets:
        json.dump(data,f1)
        listoftweets[tid] = 0

t.close()
f1.close()
```

Comment: could you paste the value of `line` before the error occurs? You can copy and paste it into a validator to make sure you have valid JSON.  `line` contains newline characters, I don't know if that messing it up or not but you can remove the characters using `line.strip()`

Comment: This is pure speculation, but is it possible that your file uses different linefeeds than the environment you're running Python in?  EG dos files on a linux host.  That's about the only reason I can think of for line 1 to look like it has 10166 columns.  If so, try opening the files using mode rU rather than r to trigger Python's universal line feed reading mode as described here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Are there are too many files/entries to load up in one go? If not, you could let a dictionary handle the uniquing for you. Then you don't need to check anything. Just keep adding all tweets from all JSON files to one big dictionary. Duplicate IDs will just overwrite their counterparts. Then save the whole thing out in one go at the end.

Comment: Couple of other style issues: `if not listoftweets.has_key(tid)` can be written as `if tid not in listoftweets`; use the [`with` statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example) for opening your files so you don't forget to close them; Python code is designed to be readable, so comments like `#dump into the json file` are just superfluous, making people read more without adding anything (check the `Inline Comments` section of the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Comments) for more).

Comment: @GaryFixler If there are too many files or too many entries, how does storing all the data in memory help? Currently the OP is simply storing just the tweet IDs in a hashtable, which seems like a reasonable approach when looking for duplicates.

Comment: It doesn't help if there are too many, which is why I prefaced by asking. You gave 3 style tips; this was just one of mine. It's safer not to make decisions if you don't have to. If this isn't too much data to load up all at once, then you could remove the if block, the doubly-nested json dump, the looped reloading of alltweets, and the listoftweets hash. I would consider that a win, if the dataset was small enough to allow it.

Comment: These appear not to be valid JSON files. This code loops over lines, so the lines themselves are the valid JSON chunks, stored in the JSON files exactly as shown in the posted example data. If these were created in the same way - i.e. the same mechanism wrote out each duplicate, such that they're textually identical - I would actually just `cat *.json | sort -u >alltweets.json` to remove duplicates.